# Django working with external HTMLs

Tags: python, django, html

I am writing a small Django local project (with no access to internet). Let's say i have offline standalone version of Wikipedia(I believe it's HTML5 format) as that: [image: offline wikipedia]. 

 I am trying to write a simple Django front page where user would be able to click a button and be redirected to "wikipedia_for_schools/index.html" from where all the url control will be done by that offline wikipedia stand alone page.
How is it possible to make? :/ I have tried creating a link in django template as

```
<a href="/Rachel/modules/wikipedia_for_schools/index.htm" target="content">Click to see wikipedia</a>
```

but that doesn't work cause Django complains that "http://172.30.10.67:8000/modules/wikipedia_for_schools/index.htm" Page not found, my urls.py is just

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView, name='index'),
```

and i think it's impossible to rewrite each file from wikipedia offline project to Django MVT model to provide urls, models and templates for each link.

That's how my Django project structure looks like:
[image]

And that's how offline Wikipedia index page looks
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standalone HTML pages are static files, and should be stored in the static folder and accessed via /static/.

Comment: Woho! Thank you, Daniel, made my day!